# htaccess rewrite from page ID to name not working

Tags: php, forms, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, get

I'm calling `?page=about` using the GET method in a form on index.php (ie. 'about' is a select option). Once I click submit, the URL will look like this:

`http://example.com/?page=about`

However I would like it to look like this instead:

`http://example.com/about`

but keep the script (PHP) working on index.php (do don't and don't want to have an 'about' file), ie. I would like to make use of the GET values on the same page once the form is sent. I can make the php script work, it reacts fine, but the URL rewriting does not work at all.

I have tried the following htaccess rewrite, but it doesn't do anything, the URL remains as above.

My htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

I would greatly appreciate your help, as I have no idea why this isn't working. I have searched through the net, and everyone points to this rule, yet it just doesn't do any thing at all for me.

Thanks a lot in advance!

**EDIT:**

Let me post my php code I use, sorry, I missed that. I have removed the `action` attribute for now as I'm using it in a browser that I know is sending me to the same when submitting the form:

```
<?php

$page = $_GET['page'];

switch($page){
 case 'about': echo 'I am me'; break;
 case 'galery': echo 'Nice pictures here'; break;
}

?>

<body>

<form action="/" method="get">
<select name="page">
    <option value="about">about</option>
    <option value="galery">galery</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
</body>
```

**EDIT #2:**

I had to add `action="/"` to the form tag in order anubhava's solution to work.

Comment: change `?page=$1` to `index.php?page=$1`

Comment: thanks, but that didn't change a thing, unfortunately

Comment: Is `mod_rewrite` enabled?  There isn't anything else that should be wrong with it.  The error isn't with anything you posted then. =/

Comment: I'm using anabhava's solution and the above php code [here](http://law2success.com/test/) - this is a godaddy shared hosting and i used htaccess on it with success in the past

Comment: With the link you have, make sure you remove `RewriteBase` and test it then.

Comment: Do you mean if I use it under `/test`?

Comment: why would anyone downvote this now and not even comment on ti? how parhetic...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be your complete .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#external redirect from /?page=about OR /index.php?page=about to /about
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(?:index\.php|)\?page=([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L]

#internal forward from /about to /?page=about
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: thanks a lot, this really looks like what I'm looking for, but it unfortunately didn't change anything, my URL still reads `http://domain.com/?page=about` :( - added my PHP code now; I might be doing something wrong...

Comment: Your question has been closed, I would suggest you to create a new question with all the details and links to this one, so that we can answer it better.

Comment: It's been reopened now and all details are available. If you need more, please let me know!

Comment: Pls make sure mod_rewrite and .htaccess are enabled. Also make sure above .htaccess is in $DOCUMENT_ROOT dir.

Comment: I'm using your solution and the above php code [here](http://law2success.com/test/) - this is a godaddy shared hosting and i used htaccess on it with success in the past

Comment: But that URL has `/test` at the start and this code is assuming that it is running directly in $DOCUMENT_ROOT.

Comment: sorry, I unmarked your answer as accepted, as I first thought this solved the issue, it very much looks like it, but if I make a new selection and click submit, it appends the parameters to the end of the so created URL like this: `http://domain.com/about?page=newpage` instead of `http://domain.com/newpage` - shall i open a new question for this?

Comment: See this part in my answer `RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L]` this will strip out any existing query string. Make sure you clear your browser cache and restart when testing `R=301` rules.

Comment: I tried this now on safari 6, firefox 19, opera 12.14 (all on Mac OSX 10.8) and first 2 reacted the same as described above (appending new parameter to URL), opera however does the redirect correctly but keeps the page name of the first selection forever (you can test this now [here](http://law2success.com/))

Comment: This URL worked for me in every browser i.e. `http://law2success.com/?page=contacts` became `http://law2success.com/contacts` then `http://law2success.com/?page=newpage` became `http://law2success.com/newpage` and query string wasn't shown at all.

Comment: Ahh! I just had to add `action="/"` to my form tag, and now it's working! Thanks a lot for your help with this!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 ...
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

And

> I'm calling ?page=about using the GET method in a form on index.php

Try calling the right link? '`/about`' instead of '`?page=about`'

Comment: If you're going to answer, at least use the same variable name that OP wants. =P

Comment: @Jon Tought I changed it xD