# Regex match for the whole custom querystring

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Urls of my web application take the form:

```
/cms/welcome
/cms/system-admin/groups
/cms/system-admin/standard-lists/accounting/COA
....
....
```

I am trying  to find a regex that will translate this to:

```
/cms/index.php?content=welcome
/cms/index.php?content=system-admin/groups
/cms/index.php?content=system-admin/standard-lists/accounting/COA
....
....
```

I have tried this below but it's failing giving 'The requested URL **/cms/welcome/** was not found on this server','The requested URL **/cms/system-admin/groups** was not found on this server' etc ,etc

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /cms
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?content=$1 [L]
```

My assumption here is: **^([^/]+)/?$** should match anything after **/cms/** and store it in **$1**.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.
The following rewriterules are also failing:
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1

RewriteRule ^/?([A-Za-z0-9-/]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]

Comment: Great first question. You took the time to mark it up, show what you tried *and* tell your thoughts and assumptions. One tiny point: do all your urls end with a `,` and should the be rewritten to end with a `;`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# Turn on rewriting
RewriteEngine On
# Starting with /cms
RewriteBase /cms
# If there's no file that matches the request
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# *nor* a directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Then rewrite retaining any parameters [QSA] and stop [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?content=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Can you spot what you did wrong?

> Check the RewriteCond directives

Need another hint?

> Your second RewriteCond says: Only rewrite if a filesystem directory *does* exist for the request; there's a '!' missing.

Comment: Chris don't take into account the commas and semicolons as clearly shown in my very first example. So I have tried this rawriterule: RawriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?content=$1 [L,QSA] but it is still failing.

Comment: I've adjusted question and answer to reflect that. You should not just change the RewriteRule, but change all the Rewrite... directives.

Comment: And don't forget to reload your apache.

Comment: Thanks Chris for your quick notice. Now I have just copied your answer into the .htaccess file which is located in cms folder and now I am getting "The page isn't redirecting properly.Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete."-possibly infinite loop. Thanks.

Comment: @JamesMwaiponya This RewriteRule should be internal to the server. The error you mention sounds like a HTTP 3xx redirection that goes to the browser. Do you have any redirectrules (either RewriteRule with  `[R]` flag or Redirect-directives)? This could be in the .htaccess, <Directory>, <VirtualHost> or server config.

Comment: No, I don.t have any redirectrules but in some cases I am redirecting using header('location:mycustomquerystring').For instance in this particular case I used header('location:welcome/') which translates to localhost:8888/cms/welcome/index.php but displaying the error.

Comment: Double check the conditions that send those 'location:' headers. The paths you set in those headers are relative so they get *appended* to the current url. If the resulting url gets translated to index.php and  triggers the condition again, you have an infinite loop where e.g. 'welcome/' keeps getting appended... You can check your access_log, or the network tab of the Firebug Firefox extension, to see if this happens.

Comment: @ChrisWessling you are right so I have added rewrite rules for external redirect just after RewriteBase /cms ie             RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(?:index\.php|)\?content=([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L] and I am redirecting using 'location:index.php?content=welcome' as answered here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15865499/htaccess-rewrite-from-page-id-to-name-not-working) but the url is not changing .Maybe it's the problem of the regex.

Comment: @JamesMwaiponya That's not the point... **You should make Location headers absolute**. Follow [RFC2616](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-14.30).

Comment: @ChrisWessling Thanks for your .htaccess entries. They are now working.I am redirecting using 'Location: '.PROTOCOL.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/customquerystring/' but it also broke my css,js and images links and I resorted to use absolute paths. This has helped but not fully, some forms' elements are not positioned as they used to be before using the mod_rewrite rules.

Comment: @JamesMwaiponya Sounds like you have a code cleanup due. While redirects work, they do require extra requests and all the resources that come with those. Cleaning up will make it cheaper and faster.

Answer (score 0):

This is the regex:

```
(/cms/)(.*)
```

And replace it with:

```
$1index.php?content=$2
```

I don't know anything of php or htaccess, but I think this should work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /cms
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule (/cms/)(.*) $1index.php?content=$2 [L]
```

Comment: Hie Amit Joki ! RewriteRule (/cms/)(.*)index.php?content=$1 [L] is not working. Still giving Error 404

Comment: @JamesMwaiponya, is there something before /cms?

Comment: Yes , http://localhost:8888/ or if you are looking for folder  hierarchy it's c:\inetpubapache\wwwroot\. Thanks.

Comment: I have just copied new rewriterule: RewriteRule (.*)(/cms/)(.*) $1$2index.php?content=$3 [L] but it is still giving Error 404

Comment: Even this one: RewriteRule (/cms/)(.*) $1index.php?content=$2 [L]